# Connect outlet from file to storyboard in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, iboutlet

I've got small problem probably connected with `Xcode 7`. In my storyboard I have view controller with custom class subview. This subview contains `UILabel`. In previous versions of `Xcode` I was able to create class, let say `CustomClass` which inherited from `UIView`, manually type `IBOutlet` property and connect it from class file to label in storyboard. Now it seems to be impossible, I cannot drag connection from that little circle which shows up in `IBOutlet` line.

Does any of you has the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved. I'm able to connect outlet from connection inspector in Utilities panel.

Comment: did you ever managed to drag from the little circle? I can't drag from those circles in any project, probably ever since the upgrade to xcode 7, and can't find relevant information.

Comment: I can do it now, after upgrading to Xcode 7.1.1. Very strange in my opinion. But as I said, you can connect outlets using connection inspector in Utilities panel.

Comment: Thanks for answering. For some reason I find it easier to do it from the assisting editor, that's all. I have 7.1.1 as well and still can't do it. I'm using the GitDiff plugin and thought it was the culprit but disabling it made no difference.

Comment: I'm on 7.2 and the only way I managed to get them to connect was to: 
1) Set the class of the view to the base class
2) ctrl-drag from the elements in the document outline to the declaration in the view controller class
3) Set the class of the view to the sub class